# Make printer in different subnet accessible to other subnet

Tags: routing, switch, network, subnet, packet-tracer

i am creating a network and i want the printer which is in a different subnet to be accessible by all other subnets. The router network is 192.168.10.0/24 further subdivided into /28 subnets.

[image]

The gateways are labeled.

I know this might be simple problem for many experts. but for self learning students it is quite confusing.

I have tried using static routing in the layer 3 switch, no luck. Any help will be much appreciated.

### There no extra configs.  It is new project with IPs set PCs, Printer & Router.

Router config

```
Router#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 660 bytes
!
version 16.6.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

---

Layer 3 switch

Switch#show running-confg
^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

```
Switch#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1136 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

---

Layer 2 switch

```
Switch#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1080 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: See how [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64214/8499) has the full configurations. The Preformatted-test option will automatically create scroll boxes for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using subnets, it's all the same flat 192.168.10.0/24 network. The L3 switch just works as an L2 switch. Correct the PCs subnet masks to /24 and you're done.

If you create VLANs with according subnets on the L3 switch and active its routing function then there's a lot more to do (you'd need to have non-overlapping subnets, set the L3 switch as default gateway and set static routes on L3 switch and router).